# How Can I Pass the Value of A Textfield to a Button Clicked Function in Swift3?

Tags: swift3

I need to preform username and login checks upon pressing the login button. I need to do all of this with programmatically. Anyhow, my problem is that when I create a button that connects to a function, the textfields are then out of scope.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var usernameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let usernameTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300.00, height: 30.00));
        usernameTextField.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 80)
        usernameTextField.placeholder = "username"
        usernameTextField.text = ""
        usernameTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.line
        usernameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        usernameTextField.textColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(usernameTextField)



        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system) as UIButton

        let xPostion:CGFloat = 10
        let yPostion:CGFloat = 200
        let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 150
        let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 45

        button.frame = CGRect(x:xPostion, y:yPostion, width:buttonWidth, height:buttonHeight)

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        button.setTitle("Submit", for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.black
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(button)


    }



    func buttonAction(_ sender:UIButton!) {

        let username = usernameTextField.text

        print("Username value is \(String(describing: username))!")
        print("Button tapped")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

How can I get a usernameTextField at buttonAction function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usernameTextField` is not out of scope, your app will just crash since you have hidden the property of that name with a local variable inside `viewDidLoad`. 
You should change your `let`-line to `usernameTextField =` which does not create a local variable of the same name but assigns something to the property instead:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    usernameTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300.00, height: 30.00));
    usernameTextField.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 80)
    usernameTextField.placeholder = "username"
    usernameTextField.text = ""
    usernameTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.line
    usernameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    usernameTextField.textColor = UIColor.blue
    self.view.addSubview(usernameTextField)

    ...

}
```